# Possible to use hash abilities in CanCanCan has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) allows us to quickly setup authorization in Rails via [abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities). The [best practice](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities%3A-Best-Practice) is to use Hash conditions. However,
 [scopes/blocks](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) allow more complicated ability creation.

I was wondering if there was a way to use hash abilities for a has_many relationship. For example, given an Event that has_one creator and has_many admins (and either can update the event), I believe this scope would work.

```
can [:update], Event do |event| 
  event.creator.id == user.id or event.admins.where(user_id: user.id).first.id == user.id 
end
```

Can we convert to using hashes instead?

```
can [:update], Event, creator: { user_id: user.id }
can [:update], Event, admins: { user_id: user.id } #<<< Will this work? Any gotchas?
```

Also, it would be nice to have the hashes OR in one line of code, but I can't find a way to make this work syntactically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hashes worked fine, though it seems you cannot do it on one line by design - https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#combining-abilities